# Implications of the order of subgroups, given the order of the parent is a composite number

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If you are told that the order of a group $G=x$ such that $x=x_1x_2...x_n$ is the prime factorisation of $x$. Does this imply that subgroups of order $x_i ; i \in \{1, 2,...,n\}$ must all exist?

Comment: Yes, if the $x_i$ are all primes; this is essentially Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Well, Cauchy is stronger, but yes.

Comment: If you mean a real prime decomposition with each $x_i$ being a power of some prime $p_i$ and all $p_i$'s different, then it is still true - this is one of the Sylow theorems.